# How to set style for k-grid td BUT just for one column?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using a kendo grid and for one of the column in my Kend-grid, I am using tooltip. Now, after some tinkering around, I found that for tool tip to show properly, I need to override `overflow` property on `k-grid td`class. So I did just say

```
 k-grid td {
                overflow:visible
            }
```

in my HTML and boom my tooltip was fixed. However, it allowed other columns to overflow which clearly messed up my grid. So I realized that I need a way to basically say that please `override k-grid td` BUT for only this column.  I am using Kendo Grid with Angular and my field definition looks like below

```
 {
                            field: "StateString",
                            title: "State",
                            width: "120px",                                                   

                        }
```

What should I change in the code so that I can override overflow property of k-grid-td just for this column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it turned out that I did not need to do anything fancy to solve this issue. This functionality comes built-in with Kendo-Grid. I just added a configuration item called attributes to solve this issue:

```
                   {
                        field: "StateString",
                        title: "State",
                        width: "120px",
                        encoded: true,                           
                        attributes: {
                            "class": "table-cell",
                            style: "overflow: visible;"
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a custom row template like [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/rowtemplate). give the corresponding `td` a class to be able to and apply the style only to that column.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out but I am very new to front end. Can you help me by just giving a small sample from my code?

Answer (score 0):

This is for dynamically changed cell(td) style based on value. I tried to style td based on properties. But so far what I found was solution for changing div style inside td via template. sometimes we need to work on the td itself.

For static td style in one column you can use the selected answer, but for dynamically changed td style based on column value, you cannot use the selected answer.

the trick to change the td style based on content:

1. use cell template to change the div style inside td.
2. in grid databound event. use jquery to to assign new style to the td using parent().

sample databound function:

```
function onGridDataBound() {
        //need to change cell class here, we cannot access cell from clientTemplate,
        //so we do it here after grid is bound with data and template
        $(".colorClass.btn-primary").parent().addClass("btn-primary");
        $(".colorClass.btn-danger").parent().addClass("btn-danger");

        //".colorClass.btn-danger" and ".colorClass.btn-primary" are the style we set in our cell template based on value
    }
```